# How to set username on tortoisegit dcommit?

Tags: git-svn, tortoisegit

I set up a svn server using `svnserve` to test how svn-git works.

When trying to `dcommit` I run into the problem that the tortoise gui does not give the option to choose the username, it just prompts for the password:

http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/11/31810164510-orig.png

Initially the username shown by the prompt used to be the windows authentication user (Razvan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

posting this as a temporary solution, if there is a better one I will accept it:

One solution would be to `dcommit` from command prompt and set the username:

```
git svn dcommit --username desiredusername
```

TortoiseGit will remember the username and password for future dcommits.